# Java returned boolean is false even though the condition should return true

Tags: java

I'm trying to return true from a thread,
The problem is that whenever i run the code the boolean is false.
It's strange because i double checked, and the condition is definately true.

Here's what i've done

Am i not returning correctly perhaps?

```
public class IsOwner {

    private PlayerOwnedBlocks main;
    private Config config;
    private Location location;

    public  boolean isOwner;

    private Player player;

    public IsOwner(PlayerOwnedBlocks main) {
        this.main = main;
        this.config = new Config(this.main);
    }


    public void run(Player player, Location location) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (OfflinePlayer p : Bukkit.getOfflinePlayers()) {
                this.config.setup(p.getUniqueId());
                ConfigurationSection getBlocks = this.config.getConfiguration().getConfigurationSection(".blocks");

                if (getBlocks != null) {
                    for (String block : this.config.getConfiguration().getConfigurationSection(".blocks").getKeys(false)) {
                        double x = this.config.getConfiguration().getDouble(".blocks" + "." + block + ".x");
                        double y = this.config.getConfiguration().getDouble(".blocks" + "." + block + ".y");
                        double z = this.config.getConfiguration().getDouble(".blocks" + "." + block + ".z");
                        List<String> owner = this.config.getConfiguration().getStringList(".owners");

                        if (location.getBlockX() == x && location.getBlockY() == y && location.getBlockZ() == z) {
                            if (owner.contains(player.getDisplayName())) {
                               player.sendMessage("test1"); // gets fired, but isOwner is false.
                               isOwner = true;
                            } else {
                                isOwner = false;
                                player.sendMessage("test2");
                            }
                        } else {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public boolean owner () {
        return this.isOwner;
    }
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Please make this reproducible by providing a minimal example. Your code contains many things we cannot test ourselves. Most importantly, we do not know when you start `run()` and when you check `isOwner`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make `public volatile boolean isOwner`. Without it, there is a non-deterministic time lag between a moment, when a field has been updated in a thread A and the fresh value is observable from a thread B.

[A good article about Java memory model](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html)